# Fusioncharts - Negative Y-Axis Format

Tags: fusioncharts

Is it possible to do the formatting of negative Y-Axis in fusioncharts as shown in attached image?

[Fusionchart Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LokTN.png)

Regards,
Tud.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course,

You can use the [**labelFontColor**](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/basic-chart-configurations/configuring-your-chart-data-labels.html) propertie to set the label's data color.

The problem is that was introduced since the 3.5.0 version ([Source](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-attributes.html?chart=bar2d&attributeName=chart_labelFontColor)).

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y3H2G/1440/) example.

```
FusionCharts.ready(function () {
    var topStores = new FusionCharts({
        type: 'bar2d',
        renderAt: 'chart-container',
        dataFormat: 'json',
        dataSource: {
            "chart": {
                "caption": "Positive/negative label data costumising",
                "yAxisName": "Sample",               
            },

            "data": [
                {
                    "labelfontcolor": "FF0000",
                    "label": "This is a negative value",
                    "value": "-200"
                }, 
                {
                    "label": "A positive value",
                    "value": "200"
                }, 
                {
                    "label": "Another positive value",
                    "value": "100"
                } 

            ]
        }
    })
    .render();
});
```